# How do I implement a language button in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, button

I have a swing program that is in English and I want my program to be available in another language. I am finished with the English version and I have the button for it placed in the program. I have no idea however what to write under for example actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)? I will translate everything myself, so is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)  and change text of all controls in `actionPerformed` event.

Comment: Thanks. That should work.